# Good Software Projects for Aspiring Engineers

Tags: control, slam, pid, computer-vision, software

With the pandemic going on, our school has decided to officially shutdown all sponsored club meetings. Now that we are all digital, our robotics club was looking for projects that students can do at home on their computers.

Do you have any suggestions for projects that you think do a good job at teaching important robotics concepts? So far many of the ideas we have revolve around computer vision and implementing path finding algorithms, however we just want to make sure we give our students as many options as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Harrison McCarty, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Choosing how to spend your time (books to read, classes to take, projects to construct, career to pursue etc.) may be difficult, but it's specific to you, so unlikely to help future visitors. Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess famous toy problems in the robotics/control literature which could be easily implemented in Matlab or Python are Linear Inverted Pendulum, Two-link robotic arm, and Cart-pole problem. If you need any further help with these topics let me know.